# Will New York City's new law prohibiting questions about salary history protect residents who are applying for jobs outside the city?

Tags: employment, new-york-city

As the title. I read through the law but I am not clear on whether it covers residents of the city, companies that employ workers in the city, members of either group, etc.

That is, is it a limit placed on employers operating within the City's jurisdiction, a protection granted to City residents, or both?

> This bill would prohibit employers from inquiring about a prospective employee’s salary history during all stages of the employment process. In the event that an employer is already aware of a prospective employee’s salary history, this bill would prohibit reliance on that information in the determination of salary. When employers rely on salary histories to determine compensation, they perpetuate the gender wage gap. Adopting measures like this bill can reduce the likelihood that women will be prejudiced by prior salary levels and help break the cycle of gender pay inequity.

- [Background on the law](https://nypost.com/2017/05/04/de-blasio-signs-law-banning-salary-history-question/)
- [City Council page](http://legistar.council.nyc.gov/LegislationDetail.aspx?ID=2813507&GUID=938399E5-6608-42F5-9C83-9D2665D9496F&Options=ID%7cText%7c&Search=)
- [Text of the law (pdf)](http://legistar.council.nyc.gov/ViewReport.ashx?M=R&N=Master&GID=61&ID=2813507&GUID=938399E5-6608-42F5-9C83-9D2665D9496F&Extra=WithText&Title=Legislation+Details+(With+Text))

(I don't think this question is too specific.. FWIW I do not employ or hire people. If I did I'd be talking to my lawyer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This law regulates employers, and New York City only has jurisdiction over employers in New York City, so this law would not protect residents of New York City seeking employment outside of New York City.

Generally speaking, the law of a jurisdiction can only apply to someone who has "personally availed themselves" of the benefits of operating in that jurisdiction such that it is foreseeable that they would be subject to the laws of that jurisdiction. An employer not operating in New York City seeking employees at large wouldn't meet that requirement. While this concept is usually applied in the context of the personal jurisdiction of a court, it is also not irrelevant to choice of law questions.

As with any law, there are edge cases that could be challenging in which the applicability of the law could be unclear.

For example, it isn't clear whether this rule would or would not apply to an employer looking for an employee in its Chicago office (e.g. working for the [Chicago Mercantile Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Mercantile_Exchange)) that conducts interviews and makes hiring decisions for the job at a job fair intended for NYU Alumni that is conducted at its New York City campus, even though it doesn't have offices for the conduct of its primary business in New York City and the staff conducting the job fair are based in Chicago. It might.

But, suppose that the law did apply to the conduct of the employer at the job fair. Would it also apply to a follow up interview in Chicago, or to employees interviewing for the same job at a similar job fair on the Stanford University campus? In these cases, probably not.